# why the space of smooth mappings has the homotopy type of a CW complex?

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, cw-complexes

let $N$ be a smooth compact manifold. I want to know why $C^\infty (N,\mathbb{R})$ has the homotopy type of a CW complex?  I know that if Y has the homotopy type of a CW complex and X is a finite CW complex, then the function space $Y^X$ with the compact-open topology has the homotopy type of a CW complex, [Milnor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/CW+complex#Milnor), but i can't proof a compact manifold is a finite CW complex.

Comment: yes. I want to use universal coefficient theorem for this space. for this I should proof it has the homotopy type of CW-complex. But I can't proof it.

Comment: The universal coefficient theorem is valid for any space.

Comment: It has the homotopy type of a point!

Answer (score 2):

Since $C^\infty(N,\mathbb{R})$ is a topological vector space, it is contractible (just use the contraction $(f,t)\mapsto tf$).

(It is much less trivial to say whether $C^\infty(N,M)$ has the homotopy type of a CW-complex when $M$ is an arbitrary smooth manifold.  Since smooth manifolds are triangulable, $M$ and $N$ are CW-complexes, so by Milnor the space of *continuous* maps $C(N,M)$ has the homotopy type of a CW-complex.  I believe you can then show that the inclusion map $C^\infty(N,M)\to C(N,M)$ is a homotopy equivalence, but I don't know the details off the top of my head.)